# converting file path to native path in vc++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, filepath

I am new to vc++. I have a problem in converting file path to native path.

As a example I am getting file path using OpenFileDialog in vs2010. It will gain the path as

`string ^path = "C:\path\file.mel";`

But I want to convert that path as

`String ^Result= "C:/path/file.mel";`

Please help me.

Comment: Try a simple find-and-replace loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
String ^Result= "C:\path\file.mel".Replace('\\', '/');
```